# what does this selector select "#dialog:ui-dialog"?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

This selector is refered in http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation (source code).

```
$( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );
```

`#dialog` is fine, how does `:ui-dialog` gets interpreted, i did not find it anywhere in docs.

Could anyone shed some light?

Comment: As explained in the comment just before the selector : "a workaround for a flaw in the demo system ([http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4375](http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4375)), ignore!"

Comment: I can see that. jQuery selectors do not define anything like :ui-dialog, so my question is how is this new selector added, mostlikely in jquery-ui API. but i donot know where? To explain a bit more if you try #dialog:foobar, it won't work right?

Answer (score 2):

***jquery.ui.widget.js*** defines custom selector for every jQuery UI widget:

```
// create selector for plugin
$.expr[ ":" ][ fullName ] = function( elem ) {
    return !!$.data( elem, name );
};
```

which goes through all elements and returns those with defined data (dialog in this case) object.

Try to:

1. Select dialog(s) (returns jQuery)

   ```
   $(':ui-dialog');
   ```
2. Get dialog object (returns Object)

   ```
   $(":ui-dialog").eq(0).data('dialog');
   ```

Your corrected statement:

```
$(":ui-dialog").dialog("destroy");
```

Selects and distroys all dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

The comment right above that line of code reads:

```
// a workaround for a flaw in the demo system (http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4375), ignore!
```

So it might be best to just leave it alone.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it just refers to an element whose id is dialog:ui-dialog, it doesn't have any semantical meaning

Comment: ui-dialog is the class that is used by jQuery UI. I did not find any such id in the DOM when i create a dialog in my application. But you could be right if there is some temporary element created with such id, but then it could create a lot of problems if people started using : in the ids (like #dialog:selected). Thanks (it never occurred to me that it could be a single id)